# Kubuntu - Issue opening applications that are a shortcut

Tags: kubuntu, icons

After a fresh install of kubuntu 20.04, then after update and a reboot, I have a issue that when you click on any icon that was 'add to panel as a widget' it will fail.  I get a quick tab in the panel that will show 'WSLView' then closes.

Now, if I right click and hit open new, it will work as expected.  This is a new behavior. from my previous installs.

EDIT: After additional research, I am seeing that this looks to be a Windows Sub Layer, but why as this PC is just a Kubuntu PC.

Viewing in the logs, I can see that the systemd started WSLViewer, but I cant see that this is running.

I suspected that the 'issue' may be due to fact that I used SNAP to install my applications versus APT, as this was the difference of the previous install.   I have removed all the applications, but I still face this problem when I click on a shortcut to an application in the panel.

Any suggestions to investigate this issue would be great.

Regards,

JC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar problem with the WSLView tab opening, doing apparently nothing, and closing when trying to browse a file folder from another program. I came upon a different answer on here which suggested deleting the file /usr/share/applications/wslview.desktop as WSLView had been implemented by default to handle something it shouldn't, so deleting that file fixed the problem as the correct handler was used instead. It worked to fix my WSLView problem, it might work for yours.

You could rename the file to something other than *.desktop and/or move it out of the folder to be safe, and if that fixes the problem then delete it.

Comment: Thank you, and yes that seems to fit the issue.   I did rename the file to have a .backup on the end, and I it now works as expected.   I am not sure how or why I got into that problem, but at least you helped me get out.

Comment: @Lost_Ones Glad to be of help!

Comment: Thank you very much Rob for this suggestion! Since a few days I have on my Kubuntu 22.04 laptop strange issues where default applications don't open correctly; like @Lost_Ones describes there is an WSLView icon visible for seconds in the taskbar, then it disappears and nothing happens. What doesn't work is for example Dropbox > Open Dropbox folder. But also opening a .ods file from a zip archive doesn’t work. Removing this wslview.desktop file fixes the issue. I don’t have this issue on my Kubuntu desktop. I feel this is a kind of Kubuntu issue, though I'm not sure how it started.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched my OS from opensuse to kubuntu. I found afterwords that some files I have set to run from the taskbar stopped running. After playing with them, I found that they will run if I right-click on the item, then select with the "open with" option on the menu. After some online research, I deleted WSLView.desktop from /usr/share/applications.

I have no idea why kubuntu install put it there or why taskbar goes there when I click the item, but I am glad I finally found a fix.

Comment: Please add details which release of Kubuntu you are using and whether you run a native installation or an installation inside a virtual machine or inside Window's WSL.

Comment: I'm using a native installation with Kubuntu 23.10. No vm or Windows involved.